# What is the difference between ViewController and UiViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I am trying to understand what is the difference between these two concepts.

When I speak about a controller in main.storyboard, do I mean UiViewController or ViewController? are they the same or complementary?

I tried to find some information but got mixed results, I would like you to explain it to me

Comment: What do you mean by "ViewController"? Are you talking about the `ViewController` class that Xcode generates for you in one of its project templates? Or do you mean a "view controller" in general, as in a something that controls a view?

Comment: @Sweeper I mean ViewController class. But it would be nice if you could describe
generic view controller term, because I always hear about it, but the same phrase means different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) is a class in the UIKit framework. Thing that controls a [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) (aka "view controllers") inherit from `UIViewController`.

If you create a new iOS app project in Xcode, and choose to use UIKit as the UI framework, it will generate a class called `ViewController` as part of the project template.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}
```

This `ViewController` is a view controller, so it inherits from `UIViewController`. Note that `ViewController` is just a random name for the view controller that Xcode chose, it could just as well be `YourAppViewController` or even `FooBarBaz`.

You can also find view controllers in the storyboard. Those are the yellow circles with a white square inside. If you have just created a new project, the only one there would be the `ViewController` Xcode generated. You can see which view controller class a view controller in the storyboard corresponds to by selecting it and checking the "Class" field in the identity inspector:

[image]

That iPhone-looking part is the `UIView` that it controls.